# Let $f$ be a monic polynomial such that $\lvert f \rvert \leq 1$ if $ \lvert z \rvert \leq 1$, then $f = z^n$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider an holomorphic function $$f = z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots a_0 .$$
Now if $\lvert f \rvert \leq 1$ if $ \lvert z \rvert \leq 1$, then show that $f = z^n$.

My attempt, I tried substituting $z = e^{2\pi i/n}$, and checked for $n = 1, 2$, but I don't know how to proceed in general. Can anyone provide me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the function $q(z) = z^n f(1/z)$.

Further hint if necessary:

> Apply the maximum modulus principle to it.

Comment: by maximum modulus on unit circle, |q|  = |f| x |z^n| <= 1, but at z = 0, |q| = 1, hence q = 1 and therefore f(z) = z^n.

Comment: That's correct.